# Glassfish failed start on update

Tags: java, glassfish

I have a problem with Glassfish Server. Recently(today) the Update Tool Notifier of glassfish executed an update.
Everything seemed to go well but when I tried to start the server, it threw this error.

[image]

EDIT:

```
Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
ERROR: Bundle org.glassfish.osgi-http [258]: Error starting file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfish/modules/autostart/osgi-http.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle org.glassfish.osgi-http [258].)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.glassfish.internal.api.Globals.get(Globals.java:73)
at org.glassfish.osgihttp.Activator.getStandardContext(Activator.java:97)
at org.glassfish.osgihttp.Activator.start(Activator.java:89)
at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:629)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1835)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1752)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1156)
at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:264)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

This is as you can tell a server linked to Netbeans 6.9.1 on Windows XP.

I think that is all relevant info.

Please help me. I thank you in advance.

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual text from that, not an image.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the image would resize

Comment: Are you trying to start the server through NetBeans? In the past I have had cases where I could not start the server through NetBeans but I could start it from command line when NetBeans wasn't getting involved. I can't remember what the exact error was so I don't know if it's applicable to your case but maybe you could give it a try

Comment: @Christina that worked. I don't know if I should still wait for answer telling why this happens

Comment: Glad I could help. I don't think there's a specific reason why it happens, it's most probably just a matter of buggy integration of older versions of NetBeans with the latest versions of GlassFish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just for form's sake, I'll transcribe Christina's comment to an answer.

You could try starting the server through command line instead of NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if the allocated  heap size is not enough . Try tweaking the heapsize in server settings in netbeans